# Keep getting memory_limit reached with a very small and simple script

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm running a very simple script..
It only gets one specific column from the database and writes each row value into a file
However after a short while I keep getting

> " Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 786432) (tried to allocate 24
>   bytes)"

I know I shouldnt really open the file and store 1 record at a time, however I have also tried storing the values inside an array and writing the values to a file after it reaches 1000 records but I still get the same error

My code is below & I have also increased the memory limit in the PHP.ini file to 1000M ( silly number I know but wanted to make sure that wasn't causing the issue )

```
$query = mysqli_query($dbc,"SELECT `private_key` from `data` LIMIT 50000");
$res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
$ic = 1;
$fileno = 1;
do {
    $file = fopen("data/list-$fileno.csv","a");
    $data = "$res[private_key]".PHP_EOL;
    fwrite($file,$data);
    fclose($file);
    $ic++;
        if($ic == 5000)
            {
            $fileno++;
            $ic = 1;
            }
} while ($res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) ;
```

Comment: `open, write, close. open, write, close. open, write, close. open, write, close. open, write, close` Please, don't. Give a try to `open, write, write, write, write, write, write, write, close` This can be a first step.

Comment: ahhh .. didnt spot the close after each
.. Nope still same

Comment: I think PHPMyadmin had hung and was causing the resource drain..
Just restarted all web services and running perfectly now.
Thanks for yoru help anyway @Cid

Comment: Nope just done it again .. grr

Answer (score 0):

Turned out someone else who had logged onto the pc before me had chrome open with 48 tabs open and didnt log off

Lesson here.. always check current running web applications